# cycle2 fade to white between slides

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

Is there a way to add a delay between the fade out and fade in of images using jquery and cycle2? At the moment my images cross fade, however I would like the first image to fade to white, then the second image to fade in.

My current code–

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#slideshow')
.cycle({ 
next:   '.outer', 
speed:  500, 
timeout: 0, 
pager:  '#nav' 
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="slideshow" class="pics" 
data-cycle-fx=fade
data-cycle-pager="#nav" 
data-cycle-pager-template="<strong><a href=#> {{slideNum}} </a></strong>"
data-cycle-slides="li"
> 
<li>Slide with text</li>
<li><img src="img1"/><div id="alt-caption">This is caption 1</div></li>
<li><img src="img2"/><div id="alt-caption">This is caption 2</div></li>
<li><img src="img3"/><div id="alt-caption">This is caption 3</div></li>
<li>Slide with text 2</li>
</ul>
<div id="nav"></div>
</body>
```

Thanks for your time